# Nuxt Content: How to link to binary files from markdown/yaml?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a [Nuxt Content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/) project, which fetches a number of content files like so:

**/content/resources/item.yaml**

```
---
item:
  title: Hello World
  pdf: sample.pdf
```

Which is pulled into the Vue component:

```
async asyncData({ $content }) {
  const resources = await $content('resources').fetch()
  return { resources }
},
```

Where should the PDF file go in the Nuxt folder structure? and how should it be referred to in the YAML file? I'm trying something like:

```
/content/resources
-- item.yaml
-- sample.pdf
```

and then in Vue: `<a :href="item.pdf" ...`, which always just results in `https://url/sample.pdf`, which does not load obviously. What is the obvious thing I am missing, as I can't find it anywhere in the Nuxt Content docs?

```
/content/resources
-- item.yaml

/assets/files
-- sample.pdf
```

and referencing `/assets/files/sample.pdf` also doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The [Nuxt Content docs](https://content.nuxtjs.org/themes/docs#static) describe using static assets for this.

Move `sample.pdf` to [`static/`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/static) in the root of your Nuxt project (e.g., in `static/sample.pdf`), and then use its `static`-relative path in your `pdf` YAML property:

```yaml
pdf: /sample.pdf
```